# Hypothesis test for set of Poisson trials

Tags: pr.probability

I've been racking my brain trying to come up with a way to see whether a sequence of independent $N$ binary variables $\{X_i\}$ are likely to have been generated from a sequence of Poisson trials with known probabilities $\{p_i\}$. For what it's worth, I'm ultimately interested in the limit $N\to\infty$, so some sort of generalized LLN would work. I know that I can compare the empirical mean $\bar X =\frac{1}{N} \sum X_i$ to the expected mean $\mathbb{E}[\bar X]$ and use Hoeffding's bound to find probability that $P( |\bar X - \mathbb{E}[\bar X]| \ge \epsilon) \le 2 \, e^{-2 \epsilon^2 N}$, but this leaves the possibility of false positives (right mean, wrong distribution).

I've considered additionally using a Chi squared or mahalanobis distance, i.e., $\frac {1}{N} \sum \frac{(X_i -\mathbb{E}[X_i])^2}{\sigma_i^2}$ to compare to its expected value (namely 1), but I can't prove that this doesn't allow false positives either.

It has also been suggested to me that I use some sort of relative entropic measure such as Kullback–Leibler divergence to quantify how much the sequence $\{X_i\}$ differs from an expected sequence, but I'm not sure how to relate that to a probability. The test needs to be in the form of a tail bound of some sort. My background is in physics, not stats or information science. Preliminary reading makes me think that the  Asymptotic Equipartition Property applied to non-i.i.d. variables is the way to go, but maybe this is too restrictive.

At this point any direction would be of great help.

Comment: Really disheartening to receive a down-vote  without any feedback on what I can do to improve my question.

Comment: Can you be more specific on why you don't want to use a chi-squared test here? Any method for testing if the data are Poisson is subject to potential false positives due toto random sampling error. If you have a big cost for falsely saying that the data are Poisson when they're not, then you could just be very strict about what chi-squared values you would accept as sufficient evidence that the data are indeed Poisson.

Comment: We'll, Chi squared seems to be suited to continuous data, somewhere we can apply the central limit theorem. A way to see why it's not appropriate is the case where P_i = 0.5, in which case every possible sequence has the same distance, even though some are obviously more likely than others. Update: the solution to my problem is the concept of typical sets in information theory and the use of the Shannon entropy as a way of separating the wheat from the chaff. Will update my answer when I get a chance.